Can not install Node-RED with script
I am trying to install Node-RED on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04.4 with script from Running on Raspberry Pi
bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/linux-installers/master/deb/update-nodejs-and-nodered)

But when I run this script nothing happens if I run it with sudo I get-
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory


after run curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/linux-installers/master/deb/update-nodejs-and-nodered
I get
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3128 after 1 ms: Connection refused
Where could be a problem?
Thank you for help.

Edit the question to include a LOT more information, specifically show the exact commands you ran and the output

Also are you sure curl is already installed on that machine?

I edit the question and yes curl is already installed.

You should not be running with sudo (the script uses it internally if needed). The error implies that the curl command is not returning any output, please run the following curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/linux-installers/master/deb/update-nodejs-and-nodered (note the lack of -s) and update the question with the output.

Your problem is that you have the HTTPS_PROXY or the HTTP_PROXY environment variables set to http://localhost:3128.
This tells curl that it needs to send all requests via the HTTP proxy (most likely squid given the port number) running on port 3128.
In this case I assume that squid is not running, so curl returns nothing (and the -s suppresses any error messages). This leads to bash returning instantly because there is no script to run. The error with sudo is because there is no stdout/stdin stream for bash to read.
You have a few options:

need to start the squid proxy
remove the proxy environment variables
set the environment variables to point at the correct proxy

This is not a problem with the Node-RED install script or the instructions.

Yes in /etc/environment I have setup proxy variables with http://localhost:3128 I do not know why. I am behind corporate proxy maybe this is the reason.

Then they should probably point at your proxy, not at localhost
